# Get all columns from a table dynamically within a view

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, after I save the following view:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView AS SELECT * FROM MyTable;
```

If I edit **MyView**, the asterix disappears and the SQL contains all the field names.  For example:

```
ALTER VIEW MyView AS SELECT field1, field2 FROM MyTable;
```

When **MyTable** has new fields added to it, I wish for the view output to also display those new fields.  How can I prevent the asterix from being substituted with literal column names?

Answer (score 0):

A view is a stored query for a virtual table. so changing the original table will not effect on the virtual one
so to update the view you need to delete it then recreate it

```
DROP VIEW MyView
```

then

```
CREATE VIEW MyView AS SELECT * FROM MyTable;
```

> The view definition is “frozen” at creation time, so changes to the underlying tables afterward do not affect the view definition. For example, if a view is defined as SELECT * on a table, new columns added to the table later do not become part of the view.
>   [the source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html)